# How to mimic tilt & shake controls in BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks

I am running BlueStacks (beta-1) on an old Windows laptop which doesn't have accelerometer & gravity sensor.

Many Android games support physical key mapping using which I can use physical keyboard of my Laptop to play Android games. If a game doesn't support key mapping, I can still play it.. not always effectively, but I can play it. Tap, long tap, swipe is fine with mouse.
When it comes to tilt & shake controls, many games like Ripetide GP allows to switch to touch-based controls. The problem arises when tilt & shake controls are mandatory. For example, I can't play Temple Run after few meters because of that.

How to mimic tilt & shake controls?

**Update:**
My laptop features `free-fall protection` which I guess utilises some kind of accelerometer. I don't know how accurate it is in non-linear dimension, but can it be utilized with BlueStacks?

Comment: For readers: Since the below solution dint work for me. I have explained on how to configure the tilting functionality in new bluestacks app for windows in [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/109436/tilt-left-and-right-is-not-working-in-bluestacks?lq=1) where you have to manually configure the tilting functionality of any app/game that you install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tilting, from: [Bluestacks Goes Into Beta, Supports More Apps](http://blog.18004memory.com/2012/03/29/bluestacks-goes-into-beta-supports-more-apps/)

> The latest version of Bluestacks also offers accelerometer support. No, you won’t have to tilt your computer to use it, just hit the arrow keys – the up arrow tilts forward, the down arrow tilts back toward you, and the left and right arrows tilt left and right (surprise surprise).

Unfortunately for shake as of from four months back, from: [Need to shake the "phone" how i do this ?](https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/need_to_shake_the_phone_how_i_do_this)

> This functionality is not available with current version of Bluestacks app player.
>
> Stay tuned for future version with its fix.

Comment: Wow, its working. But, what about shake?

Comment: BTW, the blog isn't correct. Tilt control isn't based on accelerometer. Its based on Gravity sensor. Accelerometer is used in case of shake..

Comment: Answer updated.