# How to mimic gyroscope-Sensor in Bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks, gyroscope

i want to play the App "Spin Commander" on my PC. For that i need to simulate the rotation of my device. Do you have any suggestions how i can do this using bluestacks?

**EDIT:** - *Better get someone who knows what Bluestacks is*....

Bluestacks is a Programm for the Computer to run Android apps on it.

In Bluestacks you can simulate an Android Smartphone

In Bluestacks you can easily simulate Phone-Tilting

I want to simulate Phone-Rotation in Bluestacks - Does anyone know how?

YES, i searched for an answer, I wouldn't ask here if I didn't.

Comment: Erm... I told you everythin i could tell you...
I am using Bluestacks,
I want to play the app "Spin Commander",
For this app I need to rotate my Phone,
I want to simulate this rotation at my pc

Comment: So what do you need to know? 
I want to simulate the Rotation of my Phone using Bluestacks at my Computer.
I tried using any key at my keyboard. I basicly want to know if there is any possibility to simulate Phonerotation in Bluestacks...

Comment: Oh, I didnt try to rotate my computer until now but I doubt that this will solve the problem.

Comment: @Stiffner I want to make a clarification that, whether by rotate you mean the tilt left/right? If it's tilting based on the gyro sensor I've got a related post that I wrote for the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Lucky, I though I made this clear, No i dont want to tilt my phone. 

I want to simulate the rotation of my phone like rotate it 90 degrees to left etc.

Comment: Check if this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110273/27149 serves your purpose for configuring the Bluestacks for game action. Pretty much same what you are asking.

Comment: this answer shows me how to tilt the phone... i dont want to tilt my phone... i want to rotate it. ROTATE! NOT TILT

Why is this so hard to understand for you guys? I dont want to tilt it, i know how to tilt it. I dont want to tilt it.
All I want is to mimic the rotation of my phone. The rotation. like 90 degrees to the left or to the right. rotation like... horizontal rotation...

Comment: I m also saying its pretty much the same step you have to follow. Have you really tried it.

Comment: Yes I tried it... If I hadn't tried it I hadn't ask this question in the first place.